# import application in word press error raised

Tags: wordpress

i have a small issues while importing application in wordpress.....i'm new to word press,Help me to fix this following issues. My colleague sent me the xml file and when i try to import in my application not allowing me to install the application

```
Import WordPress
Failed to import bp-email-type activity-at-message
Failed to import bp-email-type activity-comment
Failed to import bp-email-type activity-comment-author
Failed to import bp-email-type core-user-registration
Failed to import bp-email-type friends-request
Failed to import bp-email-type friends-request-accepted
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-at-message
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-details-updated
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-invitation
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-member-promoted
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-membership-request
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-membership-request-accepted
Failed to import bp-email-type groups-membership-request-rejected
Failed to import bp-email-type messages-unread
Failed to import elementor_library_type page
Failed to import bp-email-type settings-verify-email-change
Failed to import Media “logo002”
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} replied to one of your updates”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} replied to one of your comments”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import Media “Fintech-portal-digital-village-KPMG-Singapore-1440x564_c”
Failed to import Media “back111”
Failed to import Media “6bc80404-2200-44ae-b0fe-bbfa9b175e44_200x200”
Failed to import Media “image_2021-02-26_130115”
Failed to import Media “pexels-jakub-novacek-924824”
”
Failed to import Media “study-footer.jpg”
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} mentioned you in a status update”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} mentioned you in an update”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Activate your account”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] New friendship request from {{initiator.name}}”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{friend.name}} accepted your friendship request”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Group details updated”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] You have an invitation to the group: "{{group.name}}"”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] You have been promoted in the group: "{{group.name}}"”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Membership request for group: {{group.name}}”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] New message from {{sender.name}}”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Verify your new email address”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Membership request for group "{{group.name}}" accepted”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Membership request for group "{{group.name}}" rejected”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} replied to one of your updates”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} replied to one of your comments”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} mentioned you in a status update”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{poster.name}} mentioned you in an update”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Activate your account”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] New friendship request from {{initiator.name}}”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] {{friend.name}} accepted your friendship request”: Invalid post type bp-email
Post “Hello world!” already exists.
Page “Sample Page” already exists.
Page “Privacy Policy” already exists.
Page “Activity” already exists.
Page “Members” already exists.
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Group details updated”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] You have an invitation to the group: "{{group.name}}"”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] You have been promoted in the group: "{{group.name}}"”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Membership request for group: {{group.name}}”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] New message from {{sender.name}}”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “[{{{site.name}}}] Membership request for group "{{group.name}}" rejected”: Invalid post type bp-email
Failed to import “Default Kit”: Invalid post type elementor_library
Page “Groups” already exists.
Page “Register” already exists.
Page “Activate” already exists.
Page “Home” already exists.
Failed to import “about us”: Invalid post type elementor_library
Page “HOME” already exists.
```

should i enable some thing in the word press

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are missing some plugins :

1. BuddyPress
2. Elementor

And some pages and posts are already existing. So you need to delete those existing posts & pages manually (if you want it overwritten with the new ones).